# PHP Routing: regex not behaving

Tags: php, regex, url-routing

so I made an routing system in PHP...

So I made a route called /post/:id, but whenever I print_r my $matches I get this:

Array ( [0] => /post/10 [d] => 10 [1] => 10 ) 1

That 'd' in the array should obviously be 'id', anyone know how to fix this?

Thx

```
    <?php
    public function setPattern($pattern)
    {
            $this->_pattern = $pattern;
            $this->_regex = preg_replace('#:([a-z])+$#', "(?P<$1>[^/]+)", $pattern);
    }

    public function match($uri)
    {

            if (!preg_match("#" . $this->_regex . "$#", $uri, $matches))
            {
                    return false;
            }
            else
            {
                      return $matches;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only capture one character in your `preg_replace` call. Try this and put the **+** sign in the capture to get multiple characters:

```
$this->_regex = preg_replace('#:([a-z]+)$#', "(?P<$1>[^/]+)", $pattern);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works now. I couldn't vote up because I don't have enough reputation yet.